# title capitalization for "hands-on"

Tags: capitalization, headline-case

When using title case, should "hands-on" be capitalized like this: "Hands-On"? Or like this: "Hands-on"?

Comment: This is largely a matter of style; there is no single correct answer. Observe the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adhere to the guidance of the [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) of your preference.